# Are there any open source products that will let me share like in Instagram in my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, share

I've noticed that apps like instagram and picplz have a fairly standard screen that lets users share their photo on facebook, twitter, flickr, posterous, etc.  Does anyone here know if there's an open source product that I can put into my iPhone app that will let me do the same thing?

Specifically it would be great if there some subclass of UIViewController that had all those share options in one place.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you look for something like [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/). I didn't use it myself in any projects, but I will in future projects, because it looks really simple... :-D